# Python builtins.OSError OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python

I am a beginner is python, I am getting the above error while i am getting data for a simple route and there is no logic written i am just redirecting the user to a new template.

I have added this project on github and have switched branch is this because of that..?

I am able to open the home page properly but the dashboard is giving this issue

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for, session, logging
    from firebase import firebase
    from wtforms import Form, StringField, TextAreaField, PasswordField, validators
    from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
    import json
    from functools import wraps

    app = Flask(__name__)
    firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://androidone-43cbb.firebaseio.com/', None)


    @app.route('/')
    def index():
    return render_template('home.html')


    @app.route('/testing')
    def testing():
        return '<h1>This is another testing page</h1>'


    # Dashboard
    @app.route('/dashboard')
    ##@is_logged_in 
    def dashboard():
        return render_template('displayallusers.html')


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

The error stactrace is below

```
builtins.OSError
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
File "C:\Users\Rakeshvasal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\Rakeshvasal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Rakeshvasal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\Rakeshvasal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\Rakeshvasal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Rakeshvasal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Rakeshvasal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\Rakeshvasal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\Rakeshvasal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Rakeshvasal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "D:\Rakesh\DemoTest\FlaskTest\firebaseinit.py", line 37, in dashboard
from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_custom_frames import CustomFramesContainer, custom_frames_container_init
```

Comment: This caused by OS level. Does your home.html is the same path where your python program located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem, all the operations on the given post showed the same error, finally got this code to change the port number:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os

    HOST = os.environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')
    try:
        PORT = int(os.environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '5555'))
    except ValueError:
        PORT = 5555
    app.run(HOST, PORT)
```

my port number was previously set to 5000 by default now I changed it to 5555, u can change it to any port number

Comment: Why does it need to be port 5555? Just curious.

Comment: i am not sure too.. as per google results PORT 5555 makes possible the transmission of a datagram message from one computer to an application running in another computer...

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem, with reference to the method upstairs, modified the port number to 5555, the problem is solved. The problem has bothered me for a day

```
from  flask import Flask,jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/index')
data={
    'name':'python',
    'age':'18'
}
return jsonify(data)


if __name__=="__main__":
     app.run(port=5555,debug=True)
```

访问链接：127.0.0.1:5555/index